# Obtener valor de una variable conociendo el ID y agregarlo en Open graph

Tags: php, post

Estimados,

Tengo la siguiente duda, he tratado varias posibles soluciones pero no lo he logrado.

Tengo un formulario con un Select y 2 campos textarea.

Los campos son "Marca" con la variable $fid=15, Modelo con la variable $fid=18 y Año con la variable $fid=19. Adjunto la imagen.

[image: campos]

Necesito obtener de forma dinámica el valor de cada uno de los campos y de cada entrada que se realiza en el formulario. En este caso los valores son FORD, ABC, 2016.

para luego agregarlos en una etiqueta open graph, algo como lo siguiente:

```html
**/ necesito una funcion parecida a esto, se que el codigo esta totalmente erroneo, pero es para que tengan una idea*/

<meta property="og:title" content="'.$_POST [valor del $fid=15].'&'.$_POST [valor del $fid=18]'&'.$_POST [valor del $fid=19]"/>

**/ ejecutado deberia imprimir algo como lo siguiente*/

<meta property="og:title" content="FORD ABC 2016"/>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por su gran ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el HTML de esos campos en el formulario?

Comment: Alvaro te respondo con el código.

Answer (score -1):

Alvaro Gracias por tu interés en ayudarme. Te explico. El formulario es parte de un componente de Joomla que se llama Sobipro, hay una serie de relaciones que se hacen en Php y JS para generar un archivo XML que disfraza el nombre de las variables en el HTML final. Es fácil acceder a los archivos XML en sobipro, pero lamentablemente no me funcionan ahi los Open graph tags, al menos no como lo necesito. Por lo que estoy agregando los meta tags en una planilla header.php, me los toma sin problemas para otras variables. Pero en este caso no logro obtener el dato que necesito, te envío de todas formas el HTML. Gracias Por tu interés.

```html
<div>
    <div id="field_makeContainer" class="spFormRowEven">
      <div class="spFormRowLeft">
        <label for="field_make">Marca</label>
      </div>
      <div class="spFormRowRight"><select name="field_make" id="field_make" size="1" class="required" style="width: 350px;">
 
</select> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="field_modeloContainer" class="spFormRowOdd">
      <div class="spFormRowLeft">
        <label for="field_modelo">Modelo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="spFormRowRight"><input type="text" name="field_modelo" value="" id="field_modelo" size="350" class="required" maxlength="150" style="width: 350px;"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="field_first_registrationContainer" class="spFormRowEven">
      <div class="spFormRowLeft">
        <label for="field_first_registration">Año</label>
      </div>
      <div class="spFormRowRight"><input type="text" name="field_first_registration" value="" id="field_first_registration" size="100" class="required" maxlength="150" style="width: 100px;"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Mejor editar la pregunta para insertar actualizaciones